# Is there is any limit for order in B-tree and B+tree?

Tags: c, tree, b-tree

In a `B tree` and `B+tree` , If we specify the order as `5` then we can store the `4 keys` in a single node and `5 pointers` for that node.

It has any limit for setting the order in the above trees (or) its limit is infinite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design a system with any order you choose from 1 upwards.  If you make the order too big, it becomes difficult to find the key in the node, and the tree will be just 1 or 2 levels deep.

For example, if the order is 1,000,000, then you'd need getting on for a trillion records before you split any nodes to the third level in the tree, and you'd probably never get to the fourth level.  And you'd have to search through a million keys at each level to find where to go.  Even with a binary search, that's up to 20 probes.

If you choose a smaller order, then your searches are smaller.  For example, if the order is 32, you have at most 5 searches per level with a binary search to find the key and where to go next.  Against this, each time you move down a level, you have to read a new page from disk (if it is a disk-backed B-tree).  If it's in-memory, there's very little cost to that.

Often, you design the B-tree with a fixed page size, and tune the order based on the size of the keys and the size of the pointers.  Big keys give you a smaller order; small keys give you a bigger order.